# WinDbg - Disable source mode

Tags: windows, debugging, assembly, reverse-engineering, windbg

I'm trying to stop WinDbg from displaying source code at all.
I tried to disable by unchecking the `Debug->Source Mode` option but source code still appear as I step through the assembly.

[image]

What can I do to **completely** disable source code debugging?

I tried the following approaches without success:

1. unchecking the `Debug->Source Mode` option
2. `.lines -d` command.
3. `l-t` command.
4. Stepping by `p` and `t` instead of <kbd>F10</kbd> and <kbd>F11</kbd>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of modifying PDBs or similar, I suggest writing an AutoIt script that closes the source files.

```
While(True)
    CloseWinDbgSource()
WEnd

Func CloseWinDbgSource()
    WinWait("[CLASS:WinBaseClass]", ".cpp", 10)
    WinClose("[CLASS:WinBaseClass]", ".cpp")
EndFunc
```

Or you can patch the method `windbgx86!WinBase::Create()`:

```
0:000> .dbgdbg
```

and then in CDB

```
0:000> bp windbgx86!WinBase::Create
0:000> g
[Force opening of a window here]
0:000> bc 0
0:000> a eip
ret
<Enter>
0:000> g
```

The benefit of that approach is that you don't need to bother with any other windows as well, since no windows will be opened any more.

Comment: Hi Thomas, thank you for answering, this is not perfect as it involves patching windbg but this is the best solution so far. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

this is not an answer to disable the opening of source file window 
but a hack to reduce the annoyance it causes

if src window is bothering you on every single step
**undock** it and reduce its size and place it somewhere in a place where you wont be bothered by it

the other source files in a multi-file project will automatically open in the same place where you put your first undocked source file

you can use **alt + w + w** to activate any src file if you want to see the source maximize and minimize the window

in the screen shot below 4 src files are open but it wont be annoying you by opening and docking several times and making the command window resize on every source file open

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is a good advice, I did something similar, I used my 2nd monitor as a trash can for the unwanted windows - until I needed it hehe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .srcpath command to change the source path to an empty directory.  Windbg won't have any source code to display.

.srcpath [emptyDirectoryPath]

Comment: This won't work as the PDB has the fully qualified path embedded in it. The source search path is only used if WinDbg can't find the file specified in the PDB

Answer (score 0):

Your PDB contains the fully qualified path to your source code for each line of assembly. You can see this if you do a "u" command on your function:

```
kd> u xxx!xxxVolumeEvtIoWrite
xxx!xxxVolumeEvtIoWrite [e:\repos\clients\xxx\xxx\src\xxx_volume.cpp @ 1110]:
88c05c60 push    ebp
88c05c61 mov     ebp,esp
88c05c63 sub     esp,38h
```

WinDbg is going to pop this source code window up if your instruction pointer is on one of these addresses. There is no option to stop this, so the previous answer of hiding the window is a reasonable solution.

Your only other options are to prevent WinDbg from being able to find your source code. You can do this in one of two ways:

1. Strip the source line information from the PDB so that WinDbg no longer knows the path to the source code. You can do this either with the [/PDBSTRIPPED](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y87kw2fd.aspx) linker switch or with the [BinPlace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/devtest/public-symbols-and-private-symbols) utility
2. Move your source code to an alternate path so that WinDbg can no longer find it

Comment: By Either stripping srcinfo from pdb or altering the path you loose the ability to see the src  when you actually want to see the source on demand  one more option  is to use cdb with .lines

Comment: I don't like this solution too much, but blabb is obviously very wrong here. "When you actually want to see the source on demand" you use `.srcpath` or `.open`, etc.

Comment: When you strip you get two copies of your PDB, one with the paths and one without. Just point the debugger to the one that you want while debugging.

Comment: I think `pdbcopy` can be used too.